# How to store data with VueJS?

Tags: jquery, save, vue.js

I'm currently developing a small application to register devices on a database.

For the frontend I decided to use VueJS.

This is how I am initializing the app:

```
//App Vuejs
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#register-device-app',
    data: {
        currentDevice: {
           internalid: '',
           imei: '',
           tel: ''
        },
        devices[]
    },
    ....
});
```

I'm binding the `internalid`, `imei`, `tel` and some other fields to a form and the data is stored on `app.currentDevice` which is great.

Now I would like to push the app.currentDevice to the array devices[] so I can add more.

The problem I am facing is that if I use `app.devices.push(app.currentDevice)`, as soon as I modify the content of the currentDevice, since the object in the array is the same, the data in the array will also change, which I don't want.
I want to have the devices array to be like a local mini-database that will only hold the information until I send it to the database.

The solution I found was to use jQuery extend() `app.devices.push(jQuery.extend({}, app.currentDevice));` but I don't think this is the best solution and I'd like to know if there are some other easy and more elegant ways to do this.

Can someone leave a suggestion?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're working with an Object with no functions and just properties which you want to deep copy into a new object. If you're certain you're working with JSON-like data, you could use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, which should be a speedy way to deep clone an object like that:

```
var device = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(app.currentDevice));
```

This newly created `device` variable will be independent of the original variable and you can modify app.currentDevice without the other variable updating with it.

Answer (score 1):

In your function that handles the push from currentDevice to devices, you need to CLONE the current device object, not push it as is, as that will simply create a reference from the currentDevices to the array. If you are using ES6, you can use Object.assign(), thus:

```
hander () {
  // copy this.current device props to new empty object
  const device = Object.assign({}, this.currentDevice)
  // push this new object
  devices.push(device)
  // do whatever you need to do to reset currentDevice ...
}
```

If you aren't using ES6, you can use underscore or lodash equivalent methods, I think it's `_.extend()` if I'm not mistaken